# more flexible tagName in Backbone.js view

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js

I am trying to force the 'multiple'='multiple' attribute on a select option tag view which is a Backbone view using jQuery selector with the attr function but I can't seem to make it work. Here's my code:

```
window.MyListView = Backbone.View.extend({

tagName:'select',
    className: 'mySelect',

initialize:function () {
},

render:function (eventName) {
    $(".mySelect").attr('multiple', 'multiple');
    _.each(this.model.models, function (myModel) {
        $(this.el).append(new MyListItemView({model:myModel}).render().el);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

Not working at all. Any ideas or any other ways around this? Would I be better off creating a new view with only a select multiple tag and then append the myListItemView object to it?

Thanks a bunch,
Jimmy

Answer (score 10):

You can provide any arbitrary attributes that you want for the view's tag using the 'attributes' attribute:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "select",
  attributes: {
    "multiple": "multiple"
  }
});
```

Comment: Heh, I've read the docs and the source so many times, I somehow I still missed this.

Answer (score 9):

Likely, the reason this is not working is that your view is not attached to the DOM yet, so $(".mySelect") is not finding the node.

When you want to operate on nodes in your view during, say, a `render()` method, you want to work with the view's `el`, there are a couple of helpers in Backbone to do that.

- [`this.el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el) - your view's root node
- [`this.$el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-$el) - a jquery object of your view's root node.
- [`this.$({some selector})`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-dollar) - a jquery selector that starts at the root node.

This helpers will work on the view's nodes before they have been attached to the DOM (most commonly by the code that's creating the view in the first place.

So, your code, to add the multiple attribute would be

```
    window.MyListView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName:'select',
        className: 'mySelect',

        initialize:function () {
        },

        render:function (eventName) {
            this.$el.attr('multiple', 'multiple');
            return this;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Derick, thanks Ed, I learned a lil' bit much more of Backbone thanks to your replies.

Answer (score 0):

The select 'multiple' problem is solved now but I've tried iterating with this.collection.each(myItem)... as suggested by Ed which looks like a cleaner solution than the underscore one but even though the item is there it does not render any of the items in the view:

```
/*_.each(this.model.models, function (myModel) {            
$(this.el).append(new   MyListItemView({model:myModel}).render().el);        }, this);  */  

this.collection.each(function(myItem){ 
             console.log(myItem.id);
             $(this.el).append(new MyListItemView({model:myItem}).render().el);
    });
```

I went to see the state of the arguments in MyListItemView but they're all ok.
Any thoughts?
Thanks